# Grid layout, need 3 divs to occupy 2 columns and a row

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

I want the layout to accomplish a layout in which the first two child divs are arranged next to each other as two columns while the 3rd sits on a row of its occupying full width.

The first child column will be a fixed width (30px), while the second should occupy the remaining space.

I have tried this, but it doesn't accomplish what I need:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20px auto 100%;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: You have a layout that requires two columns and two rows, but you've defined three columns?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.child {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /*  It makes this element take all available columns (the whole row)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child one">One</div>
  <div class="child two">Two</div>
  <div class="child three">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the method I prefer.

First, you fraction in four with `grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr`. This is `column sizes / row sizes`

After that, imagine you have two squares together in the first row (first `1fr 1fr`)

Now imagine the three lines (The first line of the left square draws one vertical line, the two squares touching draw a second line, and the 2nd square draws the third one).
`|▢|▢|`

So, you say to #red, start in line 1 and finish in line 2 `grid-column: 1 / 2`, to the #green, start in the two and finish in the 3, and so on.

The result looks like this:

```css
.grid
{
   display: grid;
   grid-auto-flow: row dense;
   /* This is column column / row row */
   grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
   height: 300px;
}

#red {
   background-color: red; 
   grid-column: 1 / 2;
   grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
#green {
   background-color: green; 
   grid-column: 2 / 3;
   grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#blue {
   background-color: blue; 
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

/* To make the first row 30px you can use this instead */ 
.grid
{
   grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 30px 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="blue">Blue</div>
  <div id="red">Red</div>
  <div id="green">Green</div>
</div>
```